# Point get_header() to different plugin

Tags: headers

I'm trying to filter the get_header function on an specific page template to use a custom header located on my plugin folder.

So instead of outputting the theme header, it'd output a custom header from my plugin.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_header()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/general-template.php#L24) is not filterable. Neither is [`locate_template()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/template.php#L368).

Themes can alter which header loads by passing a parameter to `get_header()`. There is no obvious way that I see for plugins to alter which header loads. As I think about it, that makes a lot of sense. It would be fantastically easy for plugins to break themes by altering the header.

You can hook into `get_header` or `wp_head` to add things to the header, if that helps. If the "specific page template" is one that the plugin controls then you can write your header into the template.

If you explain ***why*** you want to do this a better answer may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Err, Maybe I'm overtired but why don't you just duplicate the page template and hack the get_header()

```
<?php get_header( 'edhead' ); ?>
```

Which will call  header-edhead.php instead of header.php

Then switch the page template to this template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: The OP wants to have the custom header in a plugin's folder, not in the theme folder.  Otherwise, yes, your answer is the way to go.